# UiPath : Automate an installation procedure

Tags: web-scraping, screen-scraping, robotic-scraping, uipath

I would like to use UiPath for the installation of a customer delivery
The delivery contains multiple deliverables and actions :
Open ETL tools ,Database
Edit lines in a configuration file
run a script ...
Is it possible to automate the installation with UiPath? 
If it is possible, how can I do it ?...

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: Can you provide more details regarding what do you want to install? Do you want to use UiPath to install several software?

Comment: In fact I have to automate an installation of a delivery to a customer . I have to connect to SQL server, via a connection that I have to create in advance , copy and paste scripts, make sure that my database tables were created correctly​.

Answer (score 1):

I used uipath to delivery a nice reporting robot in a similar way. Using the robot to connect to sql server, kick off some stored procs and pas the relevant parameters, then use the various activities to write the report to excel and email the client. There seem to be few limitations on what uipath can do. I didn't even have excel or an email client installed on the machine. Calling scripts and passing data between them is very easy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer
you had used just the record to do this automation ?
You had used uipath studio or uipath robot because I don't know the difference between them !!

Comment: Do I need to develop code for automation or just use the UiPath components like record ?

Comment: Hi. UIpath robot is the name of the service that executes your xaml. You build it in uipath studio, and run either by pushing play, or calling the uipath robot to run the xaml. For my solution I used the studio to build it and then the robot to run it from a schedule. I didn't use the recorder- I used the uipath activities.

Comment: I don't know if I have to use the activities or the recorder . because my sql server is installed in a remote server and I don't know how to open it and run sql script (in UiPath)

Comment: I can't use the database activities because my sql server is in remote machine and I have many script files to run ... the activities allow us to add just a request and not script file...

Comment: @FadwaBf if I am understanding you correctly, read the script as a variable and pass it into the execute activity..

Comment: I have already tried but it gives me the following error msg : "message": ".Net SqlClient Data Provider: The search for the file \" D: \\ Program Files \\ \\ MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER \\ DATA \\ \\ I_test I_test.mdf \ "in the directories ended with system error 2 (the specified file was not found.). \ r \ Nafter CREATE DATABASE. Some file names the list could not be created. Check related errors. I think it is because my sql server on the remote machine and uipath is on my local pC. it can not find the path that is specified it in the sql script

Comment: That seems to be not finding the file path... Maybe I'm clutch at straws but why has it go \\ \\ MsS.. That seems strange to me, sure it should be just one \\

Comment: I create the repository I_test in my remote machine but when i run the script with the component "execute query" it gives me this error message: {
  "message": ".Net SqlClient Data Provider : Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.",
  "timeStamp": "11:24:46",
  "level": "Error",
  "fileName": "Main"
}

Comment: I have tried the execute non query component and I had the same error message {
  "message": ".Net SqlClient Data Provider : Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.\r\nÉchec de CREATE DATABASE. Certains noms de fichiers de la liste n'ont pas pu être créés. Voir les erreurs associées.",
  "timeStamp": "10:03:23",
  "level": "Error",
  "fileName": "Main"      Do you know How can I fix the time ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to automate that process with UiPath. My suggestion is to download the trial from www.uipath.com and start to automate that process. If you get stuck don't hesitate to search for the answer in the knowledge base http://www.uipath.com/kb-articles or ask on chat/support.

Regards,
Razvan

Comment: Hello Razvan,
I just installed it and I tested the record option: I tried to connect to another machine remotely to open SQL server and execute some sql scripts but the problem is that the recorder goes fast and skip some steps